# Better JSON representation for GET ALL REST API response

Tags: json, rest, http, get

What is the better JSON representation for GET ALL REST API response? With `Option 1`, it is easier to get the details of any particular employee. With `Option 2`, we need to filter the complete array to get any particular employee details. So, `Option 1` seems to be better option. Are there any other scenarios where `Option 2` can be better?

Option 1:

```
{
  "data":{
    "1234":{
      "name":"ABC",
      "country":"US",
      "mobile":"999999999"
    },
    "1235":{
      "name":"BDE",
      "country":"IND",
      "mobile":"999999998"
    }
  }
}
```

Option 2:

```
{
  "data":[
    {
      "empId":"1234",
      "name":"ABC",
      "country":"US",
      "mobile":"999999999"
    },
    {
      "empId":"1235",
      "name":"BDE",
      "country":"IND",
      "mobile":"999999998"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For option 1, since `data` is a JSON object, the order is not preserved and you cannot iterate over it in order. This may or may not be an issue depending on your use case. If this data is being consumed by a front-end app and you want to display the employees in order, then option 2 would be more suitable. If ordering doesn't matter, go with option 1.